# page 10 second paragraph from the bottom / page 10 second paragraph below?

Tags: adverbs

Which one is correct?

1. see page 10, second paragraph from the bottom
2. see page 10, second paragraph below

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct. The second one doesn't make sense.

You could also try "second to last paragraph" or "penultimate paragraph" but I think your option 1 is the most natural sounding when using this sentence structure.